# Accessing required-function when js files are in Data folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using Mozilla Addon builder (Node.js/common.js) to build a FireFox addon. Please note, I have the files in question (explained later) in the Data-Folder that the builder gives you by default.

In the **Data** folder (comes by default) I have two files: file1 and file2:

**File1**

```
exports.foo = foo;  

functions foo() {
    return true
}
```

**File2**

```
$('#aTestButton').click( function() {

    try
    {
        //The problem: An exception is thrown due to the code below. The exception is:
        //ReferenceError: require is not defined 
        var A_Module = require('file1.js');
        var fooValue = A_Module().foo();
    }

    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err);
    }

});
```

file1 has a function I am trying to export while file2 tries to consume file1's exported function. The problem I have is that file2 throws this exception:

**ReferenceError: require is not defined**

Does anyone know how to fix this (note, it works fine when they are in Lib-folder, but I need them in the Data-Folder)?

Comment: What is the `Folder` in `'../Folder/file1.js'`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel: You can ignore "/Folder/". I removed it from the question. Just in case you are still curious, it is the folder where the file1 is stored.

Comment: `data` folder isn't meant for privileged code. Please expand on "I need them in the Data-Folder" - why? Are you trying to run privileged code from a content script? This won't work, content scripts need to message back to the main extension.

Comment: @WladimirPalant: Thanks for looking at this question. Here is what I am trying to do: (1)I need to write a function in one file and use it in another and it could be in the Data folder or in the Libs folders (makes no difference and is needed for Single responsibility principle). How do I do that? (2) Why I mentioned "I need them in data-folder" is because when I placed code in the Libs folder, I could not access js files in the ContentScriptFile attribute of Panel (i.e. data.url("file1.js")). How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Phil: you cannot share code between the data folder (can interact with content) and the lib folder ( can interact with Mozilla apis directly) for security reasons. If you need to communicate between the two, you need to use asynchronous message passing. For more info on how all of this works, see the docs: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While on your answer's train of thought, how do you build something resembling n-tier architecture on Firefox builder addon (like a js file that serves as a means of getting data, another one with business logic and main.js as your UI layer)?

Comment: It sounds like what you would want to do is create separate modules for each component?

Comment: Try this one then: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html